# Tangent of Implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So the question is
$y^2 +11xy-8x^3=-700$ find two lines tangent to the curve at the points on the curve where x=5. What is the sum of their slopes?

i got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{24x^2-11y}{11x+2y}$
but how do i get the sum of their slopes at x=5?

Answer (score 0):

setting $x=5$ and solving the equation you will end up with two possible solutions for $y$:

$y=5$ and $y=60$

Now apply those two points to your differential equation to find the tangents  $(5, 5)$ and $(5, 60)$  (assuming you differentiated correctly!)

Comment: i got the sum as $-35/13$ is that correct?

Comment: it's no hard calculations, but I want first to know how did you differentiate to obtain $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: @user3467226 how you got $24x^2-11y$ shouldn't it be $24x^2+11y$ ?

Comment: I am weak on minus signs, but $24x^2-11y$ looks OK.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, my bad !! don't know even how I managed to get the plus sign, btw I'm `weaker` when it comes to minus sign ;)